GraphQL Federation2 interface object with python and strawberry
I have a question about this https://strawberry.rocks/docs/guides/federation:
The federation2, as used in the documentation, is possible to request the books and add the reviews into the response, as resolvers.
But I wanted to know what to do if I want to request the reviews and pass the books as resolvers. In this tutorial, the graphql type functions can't solve my problem. But the interface object yes. I tried to implement this and I didn't suceed, because I have a 'resolve_type' function to implement. To be honest I'm not sure of what this function have to do.
I put a screenshot of my error.
Here is the repo where I put my developments :
https://github.com/owl2/gql-strawberry-interface-test
The federation is made with Apollo.
An idea about what I have to implement to solve my abstract class problem ?
